# 2D array size problem loading from csv file

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

```
int main()
{

    auto base_dir = fs::current_path();
    auto dataset_1 = data_names_1;
    auto dataset_name = base_dir / "NAimg_20101026_145727.csv";

    //double data[10][3];
    std::ifstream file(dataset_name);

    matrix<DataType> data_length;
    file >> data_length;
    
    auto pre_num_row = data_length.nc();
    static const int num_row = 73;//data_length.nr();
    static const int num_column = 74496; //data_length.nc();

    std::cout << num_row << "\n";
    std::cout << num_column << "\n";

    double data[73][74496];

    for (int row = 0; row < 73; ++row)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);
        if (!file.good())
            break;

        std::stringstream iss(line);

        for (int col = 0; col < 74496; ++col)
        {
            std::string val;
            std::getline(iss, val, ',');
            if (!iss.good())
                break;

            std::stringstream convertor(val);
            convertor >> data[row][col];
        }
    }

    std::cout << data[1][1] << "\n";
  
}
```

Hello, My name is Q. I want to read a csv file (here the name of the file is NAimg_20101026_145727.csv) and load the data to data array. The size of row and column of the file is 73 and 74496. Therefore, I need double data[73][74496] array. It makes error. When I make a small array, for example, double data[10][20], there is no error. Do you know what is the problem?

I have one more issue. I want to read the size of row and column from csv file and automatically decide the size of double data[row][column]. Therefore, I tried to use data_length.nc(); to decide the row and column of the double data size. Do you know how to decide the size of double data[row][column] from csv file? Thanks

Comment: Your code requires `#include`s and `namespace fs = std::filesystem;` etc to work. Don't remove necessary code for your [mcve] to be just that, reproducible.

Comment: `double data[73][74496];` will be `43,505,664` bytes that exceeds your stack sizte by at least a factor or 5. (likely a factor of 8, or 43 if on windows) Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` or dynamically allocate (`std::vector` is preferred)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you'd like to create your 2D array based on `data_length.nr()` and `data_length.nc()` that may only be known at runtime so you want dynamic allocation. One simple way to do this is to `#include <vector>` and create it like this:

```
#include <vector>

// ...

    // create a 2D vector from nr() and nc()
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data(data_length.nr(), 
                                          std::vector<double>(data_length.nc()));
    
    // fill the 2D vector with data from the file using range-based for loops:
    // Assuming csv lines formatted like: 1,2,3,4,5<newline>6,7,8,9,10<newline> ...
    for(auto& row : data) {
        for(auto& col : row) {
            file >> col;
            file.ignore(); // ignore one char (commas and newlines)
        }
    }

    if(file) {
        // successfully read the data from the file
        std::cout << data[1][1] << '\n';

    } else {
        std::cout << "failed extracting data from file\n";
    }
```

Comment: Ted, thanks a lot. I followed your code, but it does not work. I posted my code on another question. Thanks!

Comment: @Kyuwan Why open a new question? Edit this question if you need to clarify anything. ...and, I'm pretty sure my code works so please explain _how_ it doesn't work. Edit: Ok, I see that the new question uses my code instead :-)

Comment: @Kyuwan Btw, is `matrix` your own class template that you can make changes to?

Comment: I do not know why it cannot read data from csv file.

Comment: @Kyuwan I saw some suggested edits to the question, but those would fundamentally change the question so I don't want to approve those. Please supply an example of the data file and I'll update my answer afterwards.

Comment: Ted, I want to send you my csv file, but I do not know how to upload the data or send it to you? Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Kyuwan Just put an example in the question. `1,2,3,4,....` I updated the answer with what I _think_ it looks like

Comment: Thanks Ted, I do not know how to connect with csv file in your code. Can you include *.csv in your code. I do not know how to start from csv file.

Comment: @Kyuwan You have opened the file on the line `std::ifstream file(dataset_name);`, right? If so, this should extract the data from the `file` stream.

Comment: @Kyuwan Instead of suggesting that I edit my answer, please make a comment here and describe the problem. The edit that you suggested suggests that you didn't look at my edited answer. Also, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65499929/edit) to include a little sample of the CSV file (as text) so that we who answers can confirm that our answers are actually doing the right thing.

Comment: Ted, I want to send you the csv file. Can I know your email address?

Comment: @Kyuwan I'm afraid that wont help anyone reading the question afterwards. All information needed should be in the question so that others can find the answers useful too.

Answer (score 0):

The data array is placed on the stack, which is limited in size. My version allocates the array on the heap. But I guess you could add c++ operators.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct DoubleArray2D{
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    double *data = NULL;
    void allocate(int rows, int columns){
        width = rows;
        height = columns;
        data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*width*height);
    }
    void deallocate(){
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        free(data);
    }

    double get(int row,int column){
        return data[column*height+row];
    }

    void set(int row, int column,double value){
        data[column*height+row] = value;
    }
}DoubleArray2D;
int main(){
    DoubleArray2D data;
    data.allocate(73,74496);

    data.set(1,1,20.0f);

    std::cout << data.get(1,1) << std::endl;
    data.deallocate();
}
```

Comment: This is C with a slight touch of C++ mixed in. There's no need to use `malloc`s or `free`s at all. Not even `new[]`s and `delete[]`s are needed. Also, the `typedef` in `typedef struct` is redundant. It's `typedef`ined automatically in C++.

Comment: Hi NoNae, thanks for the reply. It is very helpful for me. I made DoubleArray2D data successfully. But, I do not know how to load data from csv file to the DoubleArray2D data.

Comment: How to connect data.allocate(73,74496) with csv file?

Comment: Hi NoNae, could you check the updated code? There is a problem.

Comment: Here, n_row = 73, n_col = 74496, for loop does not work. Do you know the reason?

Comment: If n_row, n_col are small number like 10 and 10, it works. But the numbers become large, it makes problem.

Comment: @Kyuwan do you start counting at 0 or at 1

Comment: NoNae, I see. how to change in the code? for (int i = 1? you mean?

Comment: I want to load (73, 74496) data to data heap

Comment: @Kyuwan try going from 0 to 73 and from 0 to 74465